# Selenium Java Code (TestNG framework) for Bold appearance of text shown on webpage

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

Can anyone provide me the Selenium Java Code (TestNG framework) for Bold appearance of text shown on a webpage .I am using Selenium RC to execute my testcases ,and i use Eclipse for selenium testscript preparation in java.

Comment: Is there a possible solution by using CSS selectors , because CSS styles are not shown in HTML of the elements I am trying to test.

Answer (score 0):

This code lists all the elements with bold text in the current page. (The code assumes that WebDriver is defined to "driver".)

```
List<WebElement> temps =  driver.findElements( By.cssSelector("*") );
for( int i=0; i<temps.size(); i++ ) {
  if( temps.get(i).getCssValue("font-weight").equals( Integer.toString(700) ) ) {
    System.out.println(temps.get(i).getText());
  }
}
```

Comment: Question is about Selenium-RC

Comment: @Maitreya can u provide the code to be executed by selenium-RC.

Comment: I'm not findig the javadoc for Selenium RC. If you can help me find it, possibly i can help you back.
(But in theory, you only need change `driver` to `selenium`.)